# C# How to store instances of a class in a list

Tags: c#, list, class, constructor, instance

I have a class named User. The class has a static property called Users which is a list to store all the users created. I want the users to be added to this list automatically when they are instantiated so I have included this in the constructor block in the User class.

I have written the below code, but when I create users with the constructor, they are not added to the Users list and the list remains empty.

Below is the code I have written.

```
public class User
{
    private static List<User> _users=new List<User>();
    private string _name;

    public User(string Name)
    {
        _name=Name;
        _users.Add(this);
    }
}
```

I know I can add each user to the list right after I create the instance of the User class. But I want to know if there is a way to do this automatically.

Also need to know whether it's better to have the list of users inside the User class, or the base class where I create each user.

Comment: That is a bad idea.  For example, it will leak memory.

Comment: Any reason why you're trying to store a list of User(s) inside User class?

Comment: I thought it would be cleaner to declare the static list inside the User class so it can be accessible like User.Users.
Please let me know what is a better idea, plus, how can I add the users to the list (whether the list is in User class or not) once the instance is created by constructor.

Comment: @YasharGharabaghian In addition to my previous comment, if the list is private, how you access it from outside? BTW I believe the code you posted works as expected.

Comment: @SLaks could you explain why it will leak memory? won't the list garbage collected at some point?

Comment: @peval27: No; why would it ever be GC'd?

Comment: @peval27 even when I make it public the users are not added to the list.

Comment: @YasharGharabaghian: You shouldn't do this in the first place.

Comment: @YasharGharabaghian If you explain what you're trying to achieve, it'll be easier to provide a solution.

Comment: @YasharGharabaghian if you call `Console.WriteLine(User._users.Count);` after you have created at least one `new User`, what do you get?

Comment: @peval27 i get an empty list. What I want to achieve is to just fill the list of Users with the newly created users, as they are instantiated. Regardless of what I've tried to do, what is your recommendation to achieve this?

Comment: @SLaks do you mean using `static` keyword instead of non static? In that case I agree. The list will be GCollected only when the program will exit. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't get added? I tried your code (but made `_users` public) and it works as you expected it to work.

Comment: @ispiro maybe it's because of the other class I instantiate the users on. That is another public class.

Comment: I too created it in another class and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using standard way to hold references of the created users.

```
public class User
{
    private string _name;

    public User(string Name)
    {
        _name = Name;
    }
}

var users = new List<User>();
users.Add(new User("foo"));
users.Add(new User("bar"));

Console.Writeline(users.Count); // this will say 2!
// you can now use your list of users.
```